# Hawk Authentication using retrofit in android

Tags: android, authentication, retrofit2, okhttp

I am building an app which uses hawk authentication for apis. I am using retrofit for implementing api in the app. One of the few articles I found which explains how to do use hawk auth in retrofit is https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-hawk-authentication-on-android. This article mentions a class *HawkAuthenticationInterceptor* which i couldn't find anywhere. Is there any other way of adding hawk authorization header using retrofit.

Update : I am currently computing hawk auth on separate thread and adding it through @Authorization header. Also, in the current implementation the hawk credentials is based on timestamp and uses *Hawk.calculateMAC*. The final authorization header consists of hawkId,timestamp, nonce and mac.

Ex : Hawk id="hawkId", ts="15912131366", nonce="CQMZ4B", mac="W0n/pffeysCnj20OEk4WoeO86W5r2Pi9ZgjR2kre6SU="

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: The solution you posted is generic, The solution i was looking for was different. I didn't notice it at the time of posting. I will update the question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

[Tauntz on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/tauntz/) referenced the following solution

```
package br.com.xplore.xploreretrofit1.interceptors;

import com.wealdtech.hawk.HawkClient;
import com.wealdtech.hawk.HawkCredentials;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

/**
 * Created by r028367 on 29/11/2017.
 */

public class HawkAuthenticationInterceptor implements Interceptor{

    private HawkClient hawkClient;

    public HawkAuthenticationInterceptor(HawkCredentials hawkCredentials) {
        this.hawkClient = new HawkClient.Builder()
                .credentials(hawkCredentials).build();

    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();
        URI uri = original.url().uri();
        String method = original.method();
        String header = hawkClient
                .generateAuthorizationHeader(uri, method, null
                        , null, null, null);
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", header)
                .method(method, original.body());
        return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

https://github.com/chrislucas/xplore-retrofit-android/blob/master/XploreRetrofit1/app/src/main/java/br/com/xplore/xploreretrofit1/interceptors/HawkAuthenticationInterceptor.java